# How to calculate the probability of an event with 10% chance of happening occurs ten times in a row.

Tags: probability

Let's say you are playing a game of chance. To win the game an event has to occur. That event only has a 10% to occur. You can play the game 10 times. How should we calculate the probability of winning the game

1. At least once
2. All ten times
3. Zero times.

For the $2^{nd}$ one, I know I have to add probabilities if events are independent of each other. But when I add the probabilities of winning ten times, i.e, $\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{10} = 10*\frac{1}{10} = 1$. Which obviously isn't true. I'm still new to probability, so did I do something wrong for the second one.

Comment: For the $2$nd one, you don't add them, you multiply them... And for this whole problem you should be using the Binomial distribution for the random variable, "number of wins out of $10.$"

Comment: @AdamRubinson, Why should I multiply them, and can you please provide me sources to learn about Binomial distribution. I'm fairly new to probability so I want to learn more.

Comment: Think of a simpler example. If you toss a fair coin twice, the probability of getting three heads is $\frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 = \frac18.$ That's just the rule, I guess. You can also draw a probability/decision tree and you have to multiply the probability of each branch of the tree to get the probability of an outcome (e.g. $HHH$). For the Binomial distribution, start with the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Example

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks, that example makes it easier to understand. So for the binomial distribution you need the total events, number of desired events and the probability of the desired events right?

Comment: yes. Desired outcomes are called "successes". For the Binomial distribution to be valid, four conditions must be met: 1. Probability $p$ is constant (i.e. not change in probability in different coin tosses), 2. The events (e.g. "tossing a coin") must be independent from one another, 3. There must be only a "success" (e.g. "getting heads") and a failure (e.g. "getting tails") and no other options. 4. There must be a fixed number of trails, which was $6$ in the wikipedia example. If these four conditions are met, then we may use the Binomial distribution.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, Since the function needs exact number of successes wanted, I'm guessing that I have to calculate the probability of winning zero times, by putting the number of successes as 0, and subtract it from 1 to get the probability of winning at least once. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Good thinking.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, The answers that I'm getting are, 1) 65.132%, 2) $1/10^8$% and 3) 34.868%. I'm not that confident about the first one though.

Comment: Those are all correct. Note that the answers to $(1)$ and $(3)$ add up to $100$%, as expected...

Comment: @AdamRubinson, yes they do, thanks for helping me mate, now I feel relieved as the answers are right

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good "rule of thumb" with probability is that when you have "and", you multiply, and when you have "or", you add.

So in this case you want to win game 1 $\textbf{and}$ game 2 and so on, which means your computation is:
$$\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{10^{10}}$$

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, so what about 1 and 3

Comment: I won't do the exact workings here, but for Q1, it's much easier to work out the probability of winning no times, and winning exactly once, and subtracting them from 1 (You can imagine this as "the whole probability minus the probability I win no times, and the probability I win exactly once, leaving me with the probability I win at least once"). 

For Q3, it's the exact same method as Q2, but replace each probability with the probability that you do not win. (For a hint: If the chance of winning is 1/10, and the whole probability is 1, what must the chance of losing be?)

Comment: but isn't winning exactly once considered as winning at least once. So shouldn't I only subtract the probability of winning zero times from one to get the probability of winning at least once.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, So you only need to subtract winning zero times from the full probability

Comment: that's good to know. Thanks for helping me.